# Selecting selector item dynamically with jquery

Tags: jquery

i have dynamically loaded a course selection dropdown with php and jquery as per the html code given below.this is for one selector and similar exist for more selectors. on clicking the selector it drops down the courses list and any other selector if open gets wrapped up.
Every heading is given an id in the  tag and accordingly i am trying to drop down the selector based on the id which i get from streamid .i.e if streamid is 2 i shall drop down selector with a href id=2.

```
<ul id='nav'>
             <li><a href='#' id='2' >Information Technology<span class='right_icon'><img src='images/icon.png' /></a></span><ul><a href='coursedetail.php?courseid=2&amp;streamid=2'><li class='lidiv'><span class='do_img'><img src='images/do.png' /></span>B.Sc(IT)</li></a>
              <a href='coursedetail.php?courseid=11&amp;streamid=2'><li class='lidiv'><span class='do_img'><img src='images/do.png' /></span>M.tech(IT)</li></a>

                        <a href='coursedetail.php?courseid=24&amp;streamid=2'><li class='lidiv'><span class='do_img'><img src='images/do.png' /></span>Diploma in Hardware & Networking</li></a>
              <a href='coursedetail.php?courseid=25&amp;streamid=2'><li class='lidiv'><span class='do_img'><img src='images/do.png' /></span>DIT</li></a>
              </ul></li></ul>
```

here is the code i am trying to drop down the selector with jquery

```
$("#nav > li > #<?php echo $stream; ?>").next("ul").slideDown(350);
```

but it is not working . here $stream is the streamid as written above.
also if i were to highlight the course too which is a child of ul what jquery code i need to write.

thanks
[image: initial position]
[image: on drop down]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#nav > li").eq(<?php echo $stream; ?>).next("ul").slideDown(350);
```

Comment: this is what it outputs to the page$("#nav > li >" + " "+ 4).next("ul").slideDown(350);